# Find all twice-differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find all twice- differentiable functions $f$ such that the
average value of $f$ on each closed subinterval of $[a,b],$ $a < b,$ is the
mean of $f$ at the endpoints of the subinterval. Please give me a hint how to start.

Comment: Write down $(b-a)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$ and differentiate with respect to $a$ and then with respect to $b$.

Answer (score 3):

You get
$$
(b-a)\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt
$$
which translates into the initial value problem
$$
(x-a)f'(x)+(A+f(x))=2f(x), \qquad f(a)=A
$$